# Many to Many relationship check if data exist

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, many-to-many

**UPDATE**

Ok, so i have basic table:
[image]

So i edited my question to simple version, i want to check if the Current Admin have the privilege assigned in the database..

**Example Controller:**

```
public ActionResult CreateAdmin()
{
    //get Admin Session ID
    var getAdmin = db.ms_admin
            .Include(s => s.ms_admin_priviledge)
            .Where(s => s.ID.ToString() == User.Identity.Name.ToString());

    //there error in the if...
    if(getAdmin.ms_admin_privilege.admin_privilege.Contains("privilege1"))
    { 
        //do something
    }
    else(getAdmin.ms_admin_privilege.admin_privilege.Contains("privilege2"))
    {
        //do another one
    }

    // bla bla
}
```

i'm not really familiar with many-to-many relationship in entity framework...

thank you very much

Comment: yes you are doing in a correct way so what's the problem??

Comment: i like to know the "if" method that i should use in asp.net mvc code.. cause this is a many-to-many relationship..

Answer (score 0):

Get List of Admin privilege from database like **select admin_privilege_id from admin_has_privilege where ID=Admin ID**

```
public ActionResult CreateAdmin()
{

    var current_admin_id = //Admin Session ID
   List<int> lstadmin_privilege_id =new        List<int> ();
    //set lstadmin_privilege_id  from database values
    if (! lstadmin_privilege_id.Contains(**your_required_privilege_id**))
    {

        return RedirectToAction("login")//here you forgot to write return Keyword
    }
}
```

Comment: the **your_required_privilege_id** is a string?? let just say i have 3 adminPrivilege: create privilege, edit privilege, & delete privilege should i make multiple if??

Comment: no just put if condition where you need..and required_privilege_id is int and in case you have string than get list of string from database for select query .

Comment: sorry for the late reply, i try my best to understand your code, but i'm having a hard time figure it out, so i change my question into a simple one, hope you understand what i mean...

Answer (score 0):

Yes the way you are approaching is correct with **if else(you can use as many conditions as you want)** as shown:

```
public ActionResult CreateAdmin()
{
   var current_admin_id = //Admin Session ID
   if(//current admin don't have the necessary privilege to enter this controller//)
   {
     return RedirectToAction("login")//here you forgot to write return Keyword
   }
   else if(...){...}
   else if(...){...}
   else
   {
    return View();
   }
}
```

**NOTE :-** **You can also use custom action filters for this purpose more information on custom filters is** [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/426766/Custom-Filters-in-MVC-Authorization-Action-Result) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg416513(v=vs.98).aspx) and [here](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/b11a280114-Understanding-ASP.NET-MVC-Filters-and-Attributes.html)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem earlier which i solved as follows.

First create a class as follows

```
public class HasPermission : AuthorizeAttribute
    {  
        protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
        {
            bool baseAuthorized = base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
            if (!baseAuthorized)
            {
                return false;
            }
            //Your code here
            if (!hasPermission)
            {
                return false;
            }
            //Your code ends here
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Now use it on any method you want like below

`[HasPermission]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
              return View();
        }`